# Implementing a trait that has associated trait types

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

I'm having trouble learning about associated types. My problem code:

```
trait Fooer {
    fn foo(&self);
}

trait FooStore {
    type T: Fooer;
    fn store_foo(&self, fooer: Self::T);
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
struct DB {}

impl FooStore for DB {
    type T = Fooer;

    fn store_foo(&self, _fooer: Self::T) {}
}

fn main() {}
```

[Play link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%0A%0Atrait%20Fooer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20foo(%26self)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20FooStore%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20T%3A%20Fooer%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20store_foo(%26self%2C%20fooer%3A%20Self%3A%3AT)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Ballow(dead_code)%5D%0Astruct%20DB%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20FooStore%20for%20DB%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20T%20%3D%20Fooer%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20store_foo(%26self%2C%20_fooer%3A%20Self%3A%3AT)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%7D%0A&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

The intent here is to use associated types to make the `FooStore` trait not require the awkward and problematic syntax of `impl<F:Fooer, T: FooStore<F>> FooStore<F> for DB` because that often complains about `F` not being used.

However, the [official docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/associated-types.html) on this feature show objects implementing the underlying associated type - but not traits. In this example, `DB` does not know what structs might be passed into `store_foo(..)`, so it needs to use a trait to solve this issue.

With that said, how can I get an associated type to use a trait during `impl`? That is, how can I write `type T = Fooer;`? Or am I using this wrong somehow?

**Note**: I'm having some trouble constructing this example, I'm trying to correct this now. The error I was having is:

```
cargo: the trait `Fooer` cannot be made into an object [E0038]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The intent here is to use associated types to make the `FooStore` trait not require the awkward and problematic syntax of `impl<F:Fooer, T: FooStore<F>> FooStore<F> for DB` because that often complains about `F` not being used.

Your struct `DB` needs to assign a concrete type that implements `Fooer` to `FooStore::T`. `Fooer` is a trait, but can also be used as an unsized type. However, you can't use an unsized type here, because you can't pass an argument of an unsized type by value (which `FooStore::store_foo` requires).

If you don't want `DB` to assign a particular type to `FooStore::T`, then you can make `DB` generic.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[allow(dead_code)]
struct DB<F: Fooer> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<F>,
}

impl<F: Fooer> FooStore for DB<F> {
    type T = F;

    fn store_foo(&self, _fooer: Self::T) {}
}
```

Notice the use of `PhantomData`: we use it to force the parameter `T` to be used, and it also indicates that `DB<T>` conceptually owns objects of type `T`.